# excel if function does not work

Tags: excel, excel-2010, iif-function

I have some problems with the `if` function in excel.
I have a set of data I would like to build the average only with some special values. The data is in two columns and the average should be build from column2 if 95if function. If I try a example with simple data, I get this result:

[image: result of if function]

As you can see there are values >5 but I get the result 0.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: `1.` an if statement returns true 1 or false 0, that could be the problem `2.` why do you not use the AVERAGE function to achieve this? http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/average-function-HP010062482.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem using the `averageif` function. I did not know this function, so I tried using `average` and `if`, but this is much more easier!

Comment: ok ill post it as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [AVERAGE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/average-function-HP010062482.aspx) function or the [AVERAGEIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/mac-excel-help/averageif-function-HA102927480.aspx?CTT=1) function for this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are trying to calculate the average, but the way you have used your array formulas will reference only the first cell in each array. Perhaps you want something like:-

```
{=if(max(X15:X38)<5,1,0)}
```

or

```
{=if(average(X15:X38)<5,1,0)}
```

(Replace the commas with semicolons if that is required by your language settings.)